# Drag zoom in Quantum GIS missing?

Tags: qgis

There are like ten zoom-tool icons but no one seems to do what I look for - to zoom to a rectangle that will be created by dragging mouse from top left corner of it to bottom right corner of the rectangle.

Can you please tell me how to achieve this in Quantum GIS? I am using the latest 1.8.0-Lisboa version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon with the magnifying glass and the plus in the "map navigation" toolbar does exactly what you describe.

[image]

Comment: thanks! I see it now... There amount of icons which are there somehow distracted me; there are other icons which looked much more competent for my goal...